# Is this an example of basis vector?

Tags: linear-algebra

$
\begin {bmatrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & 1\\
\end {bmatrix}
$
$
\begin {bmatrix}
3\\
2\\
\end {bmatrix}
$ = $
\begin {bmatrix}
3 & 0\\
0 & 2\\
\end {bmatrix}
$

Is it true that [3,0], [0,2] is also a kind of a basis vector. Now, in order to express  $
\begin {bmatrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & 1\\
\end {bmatrix}
$ in terms of $
\begin {bmatrix}
3 & 0\\
0 & 2\\
\end {bmatrix}
$ as basis vector, we need to find inverse of $
\begin {bmatrix}
3 & 0\\
0 & 2\\
\end {bmatrix}
$.
The inverse will be
$
\begin {bmatrix}
1/3 & 0\\
0 & 1/2\\
\end {bmatrix}
$

Comment: To emphasize, $\mathcal{B}=\left\{\begin{bmatrix}3\\0\end{bmatrix},~\begin{bmatrix}0\\2\end{bmatrix}\right\}$ is indeed a valid basis for $\Bbb R^2$.  While you can form the matrix $\begin{bmatrix}3&0\\0&2\end{bmatrix}$ by placing the new proposed basis's vectors as the columns of this matrix, the matrix itself is not the basis.  It is however a transition matrix that converts vectors written with respect to the new basis into vectors written with respect to the canonical basis.  The inverse is the map which converts elements written wrt the canonical basis into elements written wrt new basis.

Comment: It sounds like you might have a good grasp of the underlying ideas, but you should keep terminology straight in your head and pay attention to the differences between an individual vector, a collection of vectors, a basis, a matrix formed from a basis, etc...  Part of that may just be translation issues.

Comment: You first line is nonsense. The LHS is a vector (or $2\times 1$ matrix) , the RHS a $2\times 2$ matrix. Hmm.